# Using WN-Affect to detect emotion/mood of a string

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I  downloaded [WN-Affect](http://wndomains.fbk.eu/wnaffect.html). I am however not sure how to use it to detect the mood of a sentence. For example if I have a string "I hate football." I want to be able to detect whether the mood is bad and the emotion is fear. WN-Affect has no tutorial on how to do it, and I am kind of new to python. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**In short**: Use SentiWordNet instead and look at https://github.com/kevincobain2000/sentiment_classifier

---

**In Long**:

**Affectedness vs Sentiment**

The line between affect and sentiment is very fine. One should looking into `Affectedness` in linguistics studies, e.g. http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/events/2014-ws-affectedness/ and `Sentiment Analysis` in computational researches. For now, let's call both the task of identifying affect and sentiment, sentiment analysis.

Also note that `WN-Affect` is a rather old resource compared to `SentiWordNet`, http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/.

**Here's a good resource for using SentiWordNet for sentiment analysis**: https://github.com/kevincobain2000/sentiment_classifier.

Often sentiment analysis has only two classes, `positive` or `negative` sentiment. Whereas the WN-affect uses 11 types of affectedness labels:

- emotion
- mood
- trait
- cognitive state
- physical state
- hedonic signal
- emotion-eliciting
- emotional response
- behaviour
- attitude
- sensation

For each type, there are multiple classes, see https://github.com/larsmans/wordnet-domains-sentiwords/blob/master/wn-domains/wn-affect-1.1/a-hierarchy.xml

---

To answer the question of how one can use the WN-Affect, there're several things you need to do:

First map WN1.6 to WN3.0 (it's not an easy task, you have to do several mappings, especially the mapping between 2.0-2.1)

Now using the WN-Affect with WN3.0, you can apply

- the same classification technique as he SentiWordNet sentiment classifier or
- try to maximize the classes within text and then use some heuristics to choose 'positive' / 'negative'

Comment: I also found this. Could it be helpful? https://github.com/skozawa/japanese-wordnet-affect/blob/master/create_jp_wn_affect.py

Comment: yes, it does have a hard mapping from WN1.6 to WN3.0 but it's still going to be tough, you have to check how many synsets you lose =(

Answer (score 6):

WordNet-Affect uses WordNet 1.6 offsets.

However, WordNet 1.6 is still available for download. You can use the `nltk.corpus.WordNetCorpusReader` class to load it. I wrote all the code to do it [here](https://github.com/clemtoy/WNAffect).

Comment: That looks very interesting. If you were to provide some documentation for it, I'm sure I'd be able to use it in my work (and would give credit).

Comment: @Westcroft_to_Apse Thank you, I updated the README.md to add a full documentation. Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll let you know how it works out via GitHub.