# get semantically related terms from the (wordnet)nltk package in python

Tags: python-2.7, wordnet

Can you use the wordnet nltk python package to get semantically related data? For example, get "knife" or different fruits when "apple" is given as input.

Comment: Can you rewrite your post as a question? What problem are you having, and what have you tried to solve the problem that hasn't worked? Are there other questions on StackOverflow that are relevant to understanding what you are doing? etc.

Comment: i've been just using hyponymns and hypernyms to get some data but not getting the result that i need . What i need is like for breakfast getting toast ,orange juice etc.

Comment: Then edit your question accordingly, and post the code you have written that doesn't work! You may well need to traverse the graph further than hyponyms, and I think it is likely you will need more than wordnet; eg you may need to look into upper ontologies to solve this (look at Umbel etc)

Comment: Follow the other relations, not just hypernym/hyponym. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/21902411/841830 and https://github.com/larsmans/wordnet-domains-sentiwords for domains.